# Difference between として (toshite) & ように (youni)

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice

I Can't understand the difference between として and ように.

What is the difference between these word?

examples:

> として：
> 私は君を友達として愛している。
> I love you as friend.

> ように：
> 私は君を友達ように愛している.
> I love you as friend.

Comment: Both として and ように can have multiple meanings. You need to give some specific examples that are causing you confusion.

Comment: Yes, sorry. For ex. usage of として：私は君を友達として愛している。I love you as friend. And ように：私は君を友達ように愛している

Comment: You can edit your question. So I think you should add these example to your question.

Comment: If you want to say "I like you very much as a friend (but not as a romantic partner)", 愛している is a wrong word choice. 愛している is a very big word and should not be used like a drop-in replacement of "to love (pizza, programming, etc.)" 君を友達として愛している sounds like a riddle to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「〇〇として」と言う意味は、一般的には「**〜であるものと見て**」や「**それ相応の価値で何らかのアクションを起こしている**(それがその人のやるべきことである）」などの意味で使われることが多いです。

英語だと`as`などの単語で表現できるかと思われます。

一般的には以下の様なスラングで使われています。

**例文：**

・彼は医師**として**この病院に配属している。

・救急隊**として**この使命を果たす。

・絶対に倒して見せる。戦士**として**。

---

対して、「〇〇のように」の意味は**あるものを比較して、それと類似性があることを示す**時によく使われるスラングです。　他にも、ある物事を他の物に**例えて**表現したいときに使われます。(`simile`)

英語ですと`〜like`などの単語で表現できます。

**例文：**

・彼女はチーターの**ように**足が早い。

・彼はアインシュタインの**ように**頭がいい。

・いいだろう!! 今度は木っ端微塵にしてやる!! あの地球人の**ように**!!!

---

ちなみにこれらの単語の３つ目の例文は漫画で実際に使われたことのあるスラング、またはよく似たようなスラングが使われるものです。

漫画や日常会話で使いたいなら３つ目の様な使い方も覚えておくと日本語力がグッと上がります。

Comment: Thank you much, problem was in my english, because i didn't know difference between as and like

Comment: Oh LOL.  As and like are prepositions or conjunctions. The prepositions as and like have different meanings. As + noun means ‘in the role of’, like + noun means ‘similar to’ or ‘in the same way as’.

Comment: 「あの地球人のように」?・・・

Comment: ああ、すみません。これは[トラゴンボール]と言う漫画の１コマで、すごく有名な言葉です。敵が味方の敵を爆発で暗殺した後に、お前も木っ端微塵にしてやるよ、あの地球人（爆死された主人公の味方）のように　　と言うふうに使われています。
意味をよく知らない人から見たら衝撃的だったかもしれませんね、ごめんなさい笑

Comment: And what does that 主人公 say, when he hears that すごく有名な言葉?

Comment: Of course he got very angry lol.  He said " You mean Krillin (his name) -!!!!"